# Table não é renderizada novamente depois de um setState

Tags: react, material-ui

Possuo uma tabela do Material React Ui e estou tentando realizar `sort` nos dados.

Depois que o array é sortido, minha tabela não está sendo renderizada com as novas posições definidas pelo `sort`.

Eu já chequei a função e verifiquei que os elementos estão tendo suas posições alteradas, porém a tabela não renderiza novamente essas alterações.

O que eu tentei:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    const sortBy = (key) => {
        let teste = users.sort(compareValues('login', 'desc'))
        setUsers(teste)
        console.log(users)
    }

function compareValues(key, order = 'asc') {
        return function innerSort(a, b) {
          if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // property doesn't exist on either object
            return 0;
          }

          const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string')
            ? a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
          const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string')
            ? b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];

          let comparison = 0;
          if (varA > varB) {
            comparison = 1;
          } else if (varA < varB) {
            comparison = -1;
          }
          return (
            (order === 'desc') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
          );
        };
    }
```

No meu template:

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table aria-label="simple table">
                <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell onClick={() => sortBy('email')}>Email</TableCell>
                    ...
```

Estou utilizando o `user.id` como key do meu map:

```
{users.map(user => (
                    <TableRow key={user.id}>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o componente completo? Está um pouco confuso assim, se possível, também formate a identação corretamente

Comment: @Costamilam eu consegui resolver com ajuda do stackoverflow gringo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meu problema era porque ao alterar a ordem da matriz, o React ainda encherga que aquele componente possui o mesmo estado, então ele não é renderizado novamente.

Foi necessário criar uma cópia do objeto:

```
const sortBy = (key) => {
        let teste = [...users] // make a copy
        teste.sort(compareValues(key, 'desc')) // sort
        setUsers(teste)
    }
```

E então a ordenação foi feita e renderizada.